# Is it possible to create a sub-folder directly through the GitHub web application?

Tags: github, directory-structure

Sorry if this is a dumb question.  I have looked over the documentation and my search for directory or folder did not come up except in reference to cloning entire github directories.

I have also looked over this a previous question "[How do I add files and folders into github repos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775850/how-to-add-files-and-folder-to-github-repo)", but it does not seem to answer this question.

An example of what I am trying to create can be found at https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/R with R being the sub-directory that I would like to create.

Thank you as always for your consideration,
Francis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git only tracks files, not directories. So you can't have an empty directory, it mush have at least one file in it, in order to be in git.

You *can* create a new file in a new directory through GitHub's web-interface. See [this explanation](https://github.com/blog/1327-creating-files-on-github). 
[image]
You can specify a new file in a new directory in the file name like `directory/file.r` or `dir/subdir/file.r`.

If you don't want any code in the directory, you could add a blank file named `README`.

P.S. That repo already has a directory `R`, you can see it [here](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/tree/master/R)