# how to git commit a whole folder?

Tags: git

Here is a folder, which contains a lot of `.java` files.

How can I git commit this folder?

If I do the following commands

```
git add folder_name
git commit folder_name -m "commit operation"
```

I will see the messages
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Comment: Do you have any `.gitignore` or similar preventing the folder from being added to index?

Comment: What OS are you on?  Does it have a case-insensitive file system?  Git is case-sensitive at it's core.  So, if `foldername` is really called `FolderName` on the file system, then `git add foldername` will not add the files underneath.  The path must match the case used on the file system.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You don't "commit the folder" - you add the folder, as you have done, and then simply commit all changes.  The command should be:

```
git add foldername
git commit -m "commit operation"
```

Comment: the same message is still shown. "nothing added to commit but untracked fils present (use "git add" to track)"

Comment: Then you must be doing something wrong - maybe you've already added and committed this folder?

Comment: the folder must have files inside or else git wont commit the folder itself

Answer (score 12):

To Add a little to the above answers:

If you are wanting to commit a folder like the above

```
git add foldername
git commit -m "commit operation"
```

To add the folder you will need to be on the same level as, or above, the folder you are trying to add.

For example: App/Storage/Emails/email.php

If you are trying to add the "Storage" folder but you have been working inside it on the email.php document you will not be able to add the "Storage" folder unless you have 'changed directory' (cd ../) back up to the same level, or higher, as the Storage file itself

Answer (score 10):

When you “add” something in Git, you add it to the staging area. When you commit, you then commit what’s in the staging area, meaning it’s possible to commit only a sub-set of changed files at any one time.

In your case, you want to add the folder to the staging area, and then just do a normal commit:

```
$ git add foldername
$ git commit -m 'Helpful commit message'
```

Comment: The same message is still shown. "nothing added to commit but untracked fils present (use "git add" to track)"

Comment: Are you specifying the full path to the folder?

Answer (score 3):

To stage an entire folder, you'd enter this command:

```
    $git add .
```

The period will add all files in the folder.

Comment: That would add every folder

Answer (score 2):

Let's say I `git add` many folders but want to commit each folder separately, one folder per commit:

```
git commit -m "Updating contents of 1 folder" folder_name/\*
```

Answer (score 1):

OR, even better just the ol' "drag and drop" the folder, onto your repository opened in git browser.

1. Open your repository in the web portal , you will see the listing of     all your files. If you have just recently created the repo, and initiated with a README, you will only see the README listing.
2. Open your folder which you want to upload. drag and drop on the listing in browser.  See the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0LEa.png).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. Placing a forward slash after the folder name worked for me.

ex: git add foldername/