# Can't re-structure my project with GitHub for Windows

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I created a project on GitHub, added files (basically copy-paste content from my work files) and then I realised that I wanted to:

- create folders
- move files here and there.

I installed GitHub for Windows and managed to clone my remote project locally by pressing **CLONE** at the remote repository.

Then, I created a new folder and copied there a file from my root.

Now, when I choose **Local Repositories -> open this repo** I can see my new folder and file but when I click **sync** it says "Failed to sync this branch".

I even looked at my command line:

```
git init
git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

new file:   folder/new-file
```

I tried:

```
git add folder/new-file
```

but it insists on asking a `git reset head...`.

I even tried:

```
git add -A .
```

but `git status` complains again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this

> (use "`git reset HEAD <file>`..." to unstage)

is telling that if you want to `unstage` or rather not commit the file use `git reset`.

The next stage is to `commit` the changes. `git commit -m "<Message>"`

Have a look at [How do I add files and folders into github repos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775850/how-to-add-files-and-folder-to-github-repo/8775855#8775855)

Comment: Ok, I'll look there...It seems that this: http://windows.github.com/ is far away from what this wants to download and install: https://github.com/git-cola/git-cola/blob/master/README.md#windows-installation !!!