# Uploading Single image in a git directory

Tags: php, git, directory

I have created my project repository on git. Its a web development project. I want to upload a file to it.

For other kind of files (`.txt`, `.php`, `.html`, etc.) I know I can create a new file by clicking on + button and then copying my file's content there.

How can I upload an image to the specific directory (`./img` in my case). I have searched a lot but didn't got any suitable answer.

Comment: Git itself doesn't have a "+ button". Are you talking about the GitHub web UI?

Comment: Yes I am using git website for adding data to it. There is + button next to the directory , if You are logged in.

Comment: First of all, Git and GitHub are not the same thing. GitHub is not the "Git website". Secondly, I would not advise using the GitHub web UI as your primary interface to your repository. There are a huge number of better options. Since you *seem to be* using GitHub, maybe start with their [Bootcamp articles](https://help.github.com/categories/54/articles)?

Comment: Yeah I am using github.com . ok thanks let me read the article. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method if You are a beginner.
You can add files using git add, example git add README, git add /*, or even git add *

Then use git commit -m "" to commit files

Finally git push -u origin master to push files.

When you make modifications run git status which gives you the list of files modified, add them using git add * for everything or you can specify each file individually, then git commit -m  and finally, git push -u origin master

Example - say you created a file README, running git status gives you

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   README
```

Source :: [How do I add files and folders into github repos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775850/how-to-add-files-and-folder-to-github-repo)

Comment: okay thanks . I think I have to use git console for it.let me check if it works for me.