# Upload project files to GitHub

Tags: git, github

I am very new to GitHub, and I need help uploading a folder full of project files.
When using the GitHub client (for Mac) I get the following error: "Authentication Failed.  You may not have permission to access (folder name) Check Preferences to make sure you're still logged in."

When I try to upload to GitHub using terminal, I get the following: "Could not read from remote repository.  Please make sure that you have the correct access rights and the repository exists."

I am trying to add to an existing repository (which I obviously know exists)

Any help would be most appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775850/how-to-add-files-and-folder-to-github-repo

Comment: Did you check for the obvious? Connected to the internet, have the necessary UNIX permissions, repo exists...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used GitHub client, but using terminal, I would use `git status` in the root folder of your project.

If it says "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git" then you know that you have not established a repo for that folder.  Also `git remote --v` is a good command to run to see what remotes are attached to the directory (usually, there would be two remotes for 'origin' -- 'fetch' and 'push'.

I hope that helps you to at least determine what might be missing.  If the repo and remotes are already set up well, then it might be a cloning address issue or your command syntax for pushing (if you were using terminal).