# How to add folders using Git Bash and GitHub?

Tags: git, bash, github, bitbucket

In my existing local repo, I did `git clone` from a GitHub repo, and then I have a new folder downloaded. Then I did `git add *` since [I read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8775855/4896087) that this will add not only files but also folders. After that, I did the normal flow of commit and push. However, I can only see the files pushed onto Bitbucket, with no folders...even though the folder I downloaded is sitting in my repo locally. When I do `git status`, I get this message:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Help is appreciated.

---

Share output of `git log` as per request in below comments:

```
commit 1922f3e0d535f1f840e7bd8bcd5a7a150d55186e
Author: George.Liu <>
Date:   Mon Oct 17 16:25:45 2016 -0400

    HIVE-356: Add updated reference and sample code

diff --git a/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/.ipynb_checkpoints/BidMgr API_Hive-356-checkpoint.ipynb b/Investigate BidMana                                                                                                                                                 ger API_HIVE-356/.ipynb_checkpoints/BidMgr API_Hive-356-checkpoint.ipynb
index b4ea52b..2a0860a 100644
--- a/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/.ipynb_checkpoints/BidMgr API_Hive-356-checkpoint.ipynb
+++ b/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/.ipynb_checkpoints/BidMgr API_Hive-356-checkpoint.ipynb
@@ -26,7 +26,11 @@
     "\n",
     "[Create and Access Scheduled Reports](https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/guides/scheduled-reports/overview)\n",
     "\n",
-    "[Google Cloud APIs & Reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/apis)"
+    "[Google Cloud APIs & Reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/apis)\n",
+    "\n",
+    "[Google API Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth)\n",
+    "\n",
+    "[DoubleClick Bid Manager REST API Python Samples](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-bidmanager-examples/tree/master                                                                                                                                                 /python)"
    ]
   },
   {
@@ -35,15 +39,6 @@
    "source": [
     "095673046801875030801475612094991_report/Daily_DBM_Clearing_Price_2016-10-04-2014.csv"
:...skipping...
commit 1922f3e0d535f1f840e7bd8bcd5a7a150d55186e
Author: George.Liu <>
Date:   Mon Oct 17 16:25:45 2016 -0400

    HIVE-356: Add updated reference and sample code

diff --git a/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/.ipynb_checkpoints/BidMgr API_Hive-356-checkpoint.ipynb b/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/.ipynb_checkpoints/BidMgr API_Hive-356-checkpoint.ipynb
index b4ea52b..2a0860a 100644
--- a/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/.ipynb_checkpoints/BidMgr API_Hive-356-checkpoint.ipynb
+++ b/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/.ipynb_checkpoints/BidMgr API_Hive-356-checkpoint.ipynb
@@ -26,7 +26,11 @@
     "\n",
     "[Create and Access Scheduled Reports](https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/guides/scheduled-reports/overview)\n",
     "\n",
-    "[Google Cloud APIs & Reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/apis)"
+    "[Google Cloud APIs & Reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/apis)\n",
+    "\n",
+    "[Google API Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth)\n",
+    "\n",
+    "[DoubleClick Bid Manager REST API Python Samples](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-bidmanager-examples/tree/master/python)"
    ]
   },
   {
@@ -35,15 +39,6 @@
    "source": [
     "095673046801875030801475612094991_report/Daily_DBM_Clearing_Price_2016-10-04-2014.csv"
    ]
-  },
-  {
-   "cell_type": "code",
-   "execution_count": null,
-   "metadata": {
-    "collapsed": true
-   },
-   "outputs": [],
-   "source": []
   }
  ],
  "metadata": {
diff --git a/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/BidMgr API_Hive-356.ipynb b/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/BidMgr API_Hive-356.ipynb
index b4ea52b..2a0860a 100644
--- a/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/BidMgr API_Hive-356.ipynb
+++ b/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/BidMgr API_Hive-356.ipynb
@@ -26,7 +26,11 @@
     "\n",
     "[Create and Access Scheduled Reports](https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/guides/scheduled-reports/overview)\n",
     "\n",
-    "[Google Cloud APIs & Reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/apis)"
+    "[Google Cloud APIs & Reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/apis)\n",
+    "\n",
+    "[Google API Client Libraries](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth)\n",
+    "\n",
+    "[DoubleClick Bid Manager REST API Python Samples](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-bidmanager-examples/tree/master/python)"
    ]
   },
   {
@@ -35,15 +39,6 @@
    "source": [
     "095673046801875030801475612094991_report/Daily_DBM_Clearing_Price_2016-10-04-2014.csv"
    ]
-  },
-  {
-   "cell_type": "code",
-   "execution_count": null,
-   "metadata": {
-    "collapsed": true
-   },
-   "outputs": [],
-   "source": []
   }
  ],
  "metadata": {
diff --git a/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/googleads-bidmanager-examples b/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/googleads-bidmanager-examples
new file mode 160000
index 0000000..14f4511
--- /dev/null
+++ b/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/googleads-bidmanager-examples
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+Subproject commit 14f451107adb0825839d03bc1d809b55046a1da4

commit 6b3cdba5e69468d87bc59e591b4899cc37381222
Author: George.Liu <>
Date:   Thu Oct 6 14:43:20 2016 -0400

    Add repo for bm api project

diff --git a/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/.ipynb_checkpoints/BidMgr API_Hive-356-checkpoint.ipynb b/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/.ipynb_checkpoints/BidMgr API_Hive-356-checkpoint.ipynb
index 2de2cf1..b4ea52b 100644
--- a/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/.ipynb_checkpoints/BidMgr API_Hive-356-checkpoint.ipynb
+++ b/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/.ipynb_checkpoints/BidMgr API_Hive-356-checkpoint.ipynb
@@ -15,6 +15,28 @@
    ]
   },
   {
+   "cell_type": "markdown",
+   "metadata": {},
+   "source": [
+    "## Reference\n",
+    "\n",
+    "[Get Started with the API](https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/guides/getting-started-api)\n",
+    "\n",
+    "[API Reference](https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/v1/)\n",
+    "\n",
+    "[Create and Access Scheduled Reports](https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/guides/scheduled-reports/overview)\n",
+    "\n",
+    "[Google Cloud APIs & Reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/apis)"
+   ]
+  },
+  {
+   "cell_type": "markdown",
+   "metadata": {},
+   "source": [
+    "095673046801875030801475612094991_report/Daily_DBM_Clearing_Price_2016-10-04-2014.csv"
+   ]
+  },
+  {
    "cell_type": "code",
    "execution_count": null,
    "metadata": {
diff --git a/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/BidMgr API_Hive-356.ipynb b/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/BidMgr API_Hive-356.ipynb
index 2de2cf1..b4ea52b 100644
--- a/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/BidMgr API_Hive-356.ipynb
+++ b/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/BidMgr API_Hive-356.ipynb
@@ -15,6 +15,28 @@
    ]
   },
   {
+   "cell_type": "markdown",
+   "metadata": {},
+   "source": [
+    "## Reference\n",
+    "\n",
+    "[Get Started with the API](https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/guides/getting-started-api)\n",
+    "\n",
+    "[API Reference](https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/v1/)\n",
+    "\n",
+    "[Create and Access Scheduled Reports](https://developers.google.com/bid-manager/guides/scheduled-reports/overview)\n",
+    "\n",
+    "[Google Cloud APIs & Reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/apis)"
+   ]
+  },
+  {
+   "cell_type": "markdown",
+   "metadata": {},
+   "source": [
+    "095673046801875030801475612094991_report/Daily_DBM_Clearing_Price_2016-10-04-2014.csv"
+   ]
+  },
+  {
    "cell_type": "code",
    "execution_count": null,
    "metadata": {

commit 804d2fbe74fb670b3d9e8ab208a3fdb453c4a0c0
Author: George.Liu <>
Date:   Thu Oct 6 13:45:16 2016 -0400

    HIVE-356: Add new repo for bm api task

diff --git a/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/.ipynb_checkpoints/BidMgr API_Hive-356-checkpoint.ipynb b/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/.ipynb_checkpoints/BidMgr API_Hive-356-checkpoint.ipynb
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..2de2cf1
--- /dev/null
+++ b/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/.ipynb_checkpoints/BidMgr API_Hive-356-checkpoint.ipynb
@@ -0,0 +1,48 @@
+{
+ "cells": [
+  {
+   "cell_type": "markdown",
+   "metadata": {},
+   "source": [
+    "# Investigate BidManager API for Daily Data Acquisition"
+   ]
+  },
+  {
+   "cell_type": "markdown",
+   "metadata": {},
+   "source": [
+    "The goal of this project is to research BidManager API and find out the process to use it for data acquisition. We'll also do a test with the api to get reports from BidManager."
+   ]
+  },
+  {
+   "cell_type": "code",
+   "execution_count": null,
+   "metadata": {
+    "collapsed": true
+   },
+   "outputs": [],
+   "source": []
+  }
+ ],
+ "metadata": {
+  "kernelspec": {
+   "display_name": "Python [Root]",
+   "language": "python",
+   "name": "Python [Root]"
+  },
+  "language_info": {
+   "codemirror_mode": {
+    "name": "ipython",
+    "version": 2
+   },
+   "file_extension": ".py",
+   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
+   "name": "python",
+   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
+   "pygments_lexer": "ipython2",
+   "version": "2.7.12"
+  }
+ },
+ "nbformat": 4,
+ "nbformat_minor": 0
+}
diff --git a/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/BidMgr API_Hive-356.ipynb b/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/BidMgr API_Hive-356.ipynb
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..2de2cf1
--- /dev/null
+++ b/Investigate BidManager API_HIVE-356/BidMgr API_Hive-356.ipynb
@@ -0,0 +1,48 @@
+{
+ "cells": [
+  {
+   "cell_type": "markdown",
+   "metadata": {},
+   "source": [
+    "# Investigate BidManager API for Daily Data Acquisition"
+   ]
+  },
+  {
+   "cell_type": "markdown",
+   "metadata": {},
+   "source": [
+    "The goal of this project is to research BidManager API and find out the process to use it for data acquisition. We'll also do a test with the api to get reports from BidManager."
+   ]
+  },
+  {
+   "cell_type": "code",
+   "execution_count": null,
+   "metadata": {
+    "collapsed": true
+   },
+   "outputs": [],
+   "source": []
+  }
:
```

Comment: What does `git status` say?  Have you tried `git add --all .`?

Comment: Thanks @TimAagaard  I just tried `git add --all .`, but got a blank line as output. When I did `git status`, got the same result as above...

Comment: can you try `git add .` and check?

Comment: @ParthibanN  I did, but i got exactly the same result as in my previous comment...

Comment: @GeorgeLiu Ok. `git log -p <directory name>` from the root path of the repository. Please share the output of it.

Comment: @ParthibanN  I've added the output in the main post. Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeLiu: Changes are already part of git. `git show 1922f3e0d535f1f840e7bd8bcd5a7a150d55186e` should show you everything. Possibly the mistake is in `git push` command which you have used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126029/discussion-between-george-liu-and-parthiban-n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed over the chat, Your requirement is to add the folder from another repo. Say you want to add `repoA` inside `repoB`, then all you need is to use `git submodule`

Possible help: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules
http://schacon.github.io/git/user-manual.html#submodules

Answer (score 0):

Git does not care about folders/directories. You don't see them in the log because they are not there. That is why people commit `.gitkeep` file in otherwise empty directory when an empty directory is desired.