# How do i upload a folder directly into a github repository?

Tags: java, github, netbeans-7.4

[Its a java project, i need to upload all the contents in a folder not just the source files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEc71.png)

Comment: And where is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40720141/how-to-upload-folders-on-github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git add .
```

then just push without a .gitignore and entries in your `.git/info/exclude` file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following command to have a try:

```
git add folders_name/*.*
git add folders_name/*
```

Comment: Your answer does not answer what to do after `git add` operation.