# Does "git add folder" add contents as well?

Tags: git

I have a folder for a Java project with a bunch of files inside called assignment1. If i do git add assignment1 will this also add all of the files that are inside the folder? I assume it does but im not 100% sure.

Comment: You may find this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775850/how-do-i-add-files-and-folders-into-github-repos) helpful

Comment: `git add assignment1` adds all the contents in your directory, do a `git status` to see which files are added to staging

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would take less time to try it than to type the question.  Much less time.

Answer (score 3):

[`git add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add) is purely a local operation (local to your repo): it won't "mess something up"

You can check what has been done with [`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status).

- if you are not sure, you can get back to your previous state with [`git reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)
- if you see "too much files" added, again: `git reset`, add the files you don't want in a [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), then `git add` again.

Once you are satisfied, [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit), and [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).

Answer (score 0):

Try it!

(You'll see that it does add all contents of the folder.)

Comment: Thanks I didn't really want to try it since I was scared I would mess something up.