# Can I upload a whole folder in gitlab repo via API?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

[Gitlab API Commit](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#create-a-commit-with-multiple-files-and-actions)

This I know but can't find an API to upload a whole folder containing various js, CSS and HTML files into gitlab repo.

Comment: did you get any?

Comment: @Gaurav Did u got any API's

Answer (score -3):

Does this help? [How do I add files and folders into GitHub repos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775850/how-do-i-add-files-and-folders-into-github-repos)

```
git add <folder>/*
git commit -m "<Message>"
git push
```

I often use git add -A to add all modified files. But should use `git status` before and after adding to make sure you see which files have been added before committing.

Comment: Sir, i am looking to this with API, not with this. Command line I know but i require API to do same exact work.