# How to add files on Git bash on windows

Tags: json, git, bitbucket

How do I add a folder on my pc or all of its containing JSON file to a git branch directory, 
I have tried copying the file directly but it doesn't appear

Comment: Are you trying to `git add`? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775850/how-do-i-add-files-and-folders-into-github-repos

Comment: I tried git add, but I guess I don't know the proper syntax or maybe I would have to change to the directory I want to copy from

Comment: You can also show an example usage

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps copy the folder into the same directory as the repository, and then use `git add <folder>/*` to add the folder and all its contents into the git repo