# Adding project to GitHub

Tags: android, git, github, git-bash

I have 2 Android App projects that I want to add to the same GitHub repo. I wish to create 2 folders in the repo and upload the app files to the corresponding folders. Any way that I can do it using Git CLI and Git Bash rather than uploading the files manually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add files and folders into GitHub repos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775850/how-do-i-add-files-and-folders-into-github-repos)

Comment: Nope it dosent. I have 2 different folders of 2 different project to be initialised in the same github repository. The post you mentioned just talks about adding new files of the same project. I however want to mention that both the projects are initialised under the same git repo on local machine

Comment: Those two folders are not two projects, they are the same project under a single git workflow. You cant have two git workflows for a single repository

Answer (score 0):

First of all,create a new repository from the [github](https://github.com).

Then copy the repository ssh url or https url for the repository.

After that cd to the main directory such that the two sub folders are inside it

Then type the following in the terminal -

```
git init 

git commit -m "first commit"

git remote add origin [url-for-github-repo]

git push -u origin master
```

If Your github url is `git@github.com:AnishAralikatti/Android.git`

```
git init

git commit -m "first commit"

git remote add origin git@github.com:AnishAralikatti/Android.git

git push -u origin master
```