# Static files are not loading from Static folder

Tags: python, django, static, django-urls, django-settings

I am Building a BlogApp and I am stuck on an Problem.

**The Problem**

`Static Files` are not loading from `static folder`. Some files are loading but some are not loading.

**What have i done ?**

*urls.py*

I also put `static url` in urls.py , it also didn't work for me.

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

*settings.py*

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "static")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),

]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn')
```

*my_template.html*

```
    {% load static %}

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600" />
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Next Level - Gallery</title>
    <!--
    Next Level CSS Template
    https://templatemo.com/tm-532-next-level
    -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600" />



    <script src="{% static 'comments/all.min.css' %}"></script>

    <script src="{% static 'comments/bootstrap.min.css' %}"></script>

    <script src="{% static 'comments/templatemo-style.css' %}"></script>

      </head>
          <div class="row tm-welcome-row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div
                class="tm-welcome-parallax tm-center-child"
                data-parallax="scroll"
                data-image-src="static/images/blooming-bg.jpg"
              >
                <div class="tm-bg-black-transparent tm-parallax-overlay">
                  <h2>Our Gallery</h2>
                  <p>this is a parallax background image</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

              <div class="tm-page-col-right">
                <div class="tm-gallery" id="tmGallery">
                  <div class="tm-gallery-item category-1">
                    <figure class="effect-bubba">
                      <img
                        src="static/comments/gallery/gallery-item-01.jpg"
                        alt="Gallery item"
                        class="img-fluid"
                      />
                    </figure>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>

    <script src="{% static 'comments/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'coments/parallax.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'comments/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'comments/isotope.pkgd.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'comments/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>

        <script>
          $(function() {
            /* Isotope Gallery */

            // init isotope
            var $gallery = $(".tm-gallery").isotope({
              itemSelector: ".tm-gallery-item",
              layoutMode: "fitRows"
            });
            // layout Isotope after each image loads
            $gallery.imagesLoaded().progress(function() {
              $gallery.isotope("layout");
            });

            $(".filters-button-group").on("click", "a", function() {
              var filterValue = $(this).attr("data-filter");
              $gallery.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
              console.log("Filter value: " + filterValue);
            });

            /* Tabs */
            $(".tabgroup > div").hide();
            $(".tabgroup > div:first-of-type").show();
            $(".tabs a").click(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              var $this = $(this),
                tabgroup = "#" + $this.parents(".tabs").data("tabgroup"),
                others = $this
                  .closest("li")
                  .siblings()
                  .children("a"),
                target = $this.attr("href");
              others.removeClass("active");
              $this.addClass("active");

              // Scroll to tab content (for mobile)
              if ($(window).width() < 992) {
                $("html, body").animate(
                  {
                    scrollTop: $("#tmGallery").offset().top
                  },
                  200
                );
              }
            });
          });
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**What have i tried**

- I also try `python manage.py collectstatic` and it showed  `0 static files copied to 'D:\myapp\static_cdn', 248 unmodified.`

I tried many answers AND some of were saying that `add static url` in urls.py` BUT it didn't work.

I don't know what to do

Any help would appreciated

Thank You in Advance

Comment: What's the value of the `STATICFILES_FINDERS` setting? And is `comments/all.min.css` in `{{ BASE_DIR }}/static/static`?

Comment: Hello markwalker, It worked, I copied all the static files in `app` directory now it's working fine

Comment: The answer that's been provided worked? If so you should mark it as accepted

Comment: This answer didn't helped, This answer does not relate to my solution

Comment: You should add your solution so that this question is marked as resolved 

Comment: I will do it after few hours. I am stuck on a Problem. I have a question please answer, Do you know how to push local folder in git ?

Comment: Have a look at this; https://stackoverflow.com/a/8775855/1199464

Answer (score 1):

make sure that your settings.py has the following

**settings.py**

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates")
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

the below preferably at the bottom end

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]

#MEDIA
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 


LOGIN_URL = 'user_login'
```

[image]

[image]

now create a folder called static in the base directory( the place where you have your manage.py ) and have your static files inside

make sure to {% load static %} in your template

if nothing works try opening a new project and try the above

Answer (score 0):

1. However static files dir is different from static files directory.Django uses 2 types of static folder . system & apps
2. You need to put all your static files into static files dir location then run `python manage.py collectstatic` . It will move all your applications static files to system static folder.
3. Now it will served from destination(systems static files directory) location.